IAP initialize Failed (4.12.2) GoogleBillingResponseCode: FeatureNotSupported
I used to use IAP 4.11.0 or older version in my game and it worked fine. However recently google send me notice telling me that all Apps should use google billing SDK version 6 or above before the end of 2024 August. I found that I have to update to use IAP 4.12.2. However the initialize always failed after the update, and give me the reason message saying "GoogleBillingResponseCode: FeatureNotSupported".
I can't find anything related online useful. Please help me, thank you!
How I upgrade the IAP package:

In Unity Editor on the Package Manager interface, the latest version of IAP is 4.11.0. So I found this page on documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.12/changelog/CHANGELOG.html. I clicked the link " Add version 4.12.2 by name.", then unity editor installed the 4.12.2 version IAP.
In configure tab(Project Settings-in app purchasing), I found the Google Play key somehow is re-set to empty. So I found my google play IAP public key in google's console and copied it into Unity. Then I clicked the button "Obfuscate License Keys".
Because I moved my old Google Play Tangle file to another folder, now there're two files with the same name. I found they have different content, so I deleted the old one.


It turns out the version of my play store on the device is too old. After an update, it worked now!
